# How to have dynamic link href in head

Tags: angularjs, browser-cache

I have this link element in my head in my angularjs spa:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="./images/icon/apple-icon-57x57.png">
```

I have been instructed not to have the build rename the files themselves, so I'd like to do something like:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="./images/icon/apple-icon-57x57.png?m=(some random number or date time stamp)">
```

so that upon page refresh if there's been a change to the icon it defeats the cache and loads the current icon.

But since Angularjs is not a server side technology I don't know how to make this happen.

It's ok to do it in grunt task, if I knew what task would do this.

Comment: Not sure about grunt, but I've used this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rev-mtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

controller:

```
$scope.getNumber = function() {
    $scope.num = (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9));
};
```

call this controller in your HTML tag:

```
<html ng-controller="myCtrl">
```

modify this line:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="./images/icon/apple-icon-57x57.png?m={{getNumber()}}">
```

Comment: Thanks. I simplified this by just using `$scope.revision = Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(4);` in the controller (which gives 4 digit revision instead of 1) and then using `myimage.png?m={{revision}}` in `index.html`. Works great.